# Why I got different result when use Get-ChildItem between folder that contain 1 file and folder contain 2 files or more

Tags: powershell

Example i have

\directory\1fies
     --> contain 1 file 1my.mdl
\directory\2fies
     --> contain 2 file 1my.mdl  and 2my.mdl

then i try to count the file with use Get-ChildItem $files.length, i got different result between folder that contain 1 file and folder contain 2 files?

```
[String]$CP=Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

[String]$PathtoCount=$CP+"\1file"
$files = Get-ChildItem $PathtoCount -Filter *.mdl 
write-host Count of file : $files.length

[String]$PathtoCount=$CP+"\2file"
$files = Get-ChildItem $PathtoCount -Filter *.mdl 
write-host Count of file : $files.length
```

above code give the result

```
Count of file : 542  
Count of file : 2
```

But if i use $files.count , it will give correct result

```
[String]$CP=Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

[String]$PathtoCount=$CP+"\1file"
$files = Get-ChildItem $PathtoCount -Filter *.mdl 
write-host Count of file : $files.length

[String]$PathtoCount=$CP+"\2file"
$files = Get-ChildItem $PathtoCount -Filter *.mdl 
write-host Count of file : $files.length

[String]$PathtoCount=$CP+"\1file"
$files = Get-ChildItem $PathtoCount -Filter *.mdl 
write-host Count of file : $files.count

[String]$PathtoCount=$CP+"\2file"
$files = Get-ChildItem $PathtoCount -Filter *.mdl 
write-host Count of file : $files.count
```

and the result:

```
Count of file : 542
Count of file : 2
Count of file : 1
Count of file : 2
```

Thank you for your explanation, sorry for my bad englsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a command returns multiple results they are assigned to the variable as an array of object, however, when a single result is returned, you get just the object returned. In the first part of your example, $files is being assigned a single object of type "System.IO.FileInfo". So when $files.Length is evaluated, you are getting the Length property from the "System.IO.FileInfo" object that was returned. In the next part of your code, $files is assigned an array of objects. So when $files.Length is evaluated this time, you are getting the value of the Length property from "System.Object[]". To always guarantee an array of objects is returned, you can coerce your results by using the "@( )" array sub-expression operator.

If you'll notice your code below, I've enclosed your calls to Get-ChildItem with the '@( )' operator.

```
[String]$CP=Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

[String]$PathtoCount=$CP+"\1file"
$files = @(Get-ChildItem $PathtoCount -Filter *.mdl)
write-host Count of file : $files.length

[String]$PathtoCount=$CP+"\2file"
$files = @(Get-ChildItem $PathtoCount -Filter *.mdl)
write-host Count of file : $files.length
```

When this is run, you should get the result you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you Bob for your helpful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[Bob M's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35809961/45375) explains the problem well.

If you're using Powershell **v3+**, you can also take advantage of its **unified handling of scalars and collections** by **using the `.Count` property** instead:

```
> $scalar = ''; $scalar.length; $scalar.count
0    # the string scalar's *string-length* property
1    # the *count of items* in the collection; $scalar is an implied collection with *1* el.
```

In other words: in PS v3+, `$files.Count` (as opposed to `$file.Length`) should give the desired result, even if `Get-ChildItem` happens to return only a *single* file (or none at all).